# How to find the saddle points in a 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I'm trying to write pseudocode to find all the saddle points in a 2D array. The saddle points are the spots where the value is the minimum in its row, but maximum in its column, or the maximum in its row and minimum in its column.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to store where these values occur, especially if there are 2 saddle points in the same row or column. I'm also not sure if I'm even approaching this correctly, maybe it can be done in a more efficient way?

The array is given by A[x][y] where x is the row and y is the column.

So far my (very basic) pseudocode is

```
for r=0 to y-1    // iterates through every row
    for c=0 to x-1    //iterates through every element in row r
        min=min(A[c][r])   //finds the minimum value in row r
    for p=0 to y-1         //iterates through every element in col c
        max=max(A[c][p])   //finds max in col c
    if min==max            
       saddle point=A[c][p]
```

Comment: If you have a sine wave over a period of 10π, you'll have lots of minima and maxima; you can't just look for the minimum in the column (or row).  For each value, you have to look at the next and previous values in the column (or row), and see whether the current value is smaller than both, or larger than both, identifying a local minimum or maximum.  Then you need to look in the other direction and see whether you're at a local maximum or minimum in that direction.  Only if both are satisfied at once are you at a saddle point.

Comment: Can anyone explain how to find if there are two equal minimums in a row? Say the first and last element are the same and they happen to be the minimum, how would I keep track of both?

Comment: It's a matter of definition whether edges count as maxima or minima. You could have many local maxima or minima in a single row or column. Since there could be many saddle points, you'll need to track them all — a list of saddle points. My guess is that you'll have a `for r = 0 to y-1` loop containing a `for c = 0 to x-1` loop, and the body of the inner loop will look to see if you've got a local maximum or minimum in the row direction (continuing with the next `c` if not) and then check whether you've got a local minimum or maximum in the column direction, etc. However, I've not coded it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two major problems with your pseudocode.

1) You have swapped the raws and colums

2) Passing an array element (aka value) to min/max does not make much sense. You probably should pass a row number instead and have the function to return the column number.

A simple way is to find the index of the column holding the minimum value in row r. Then find the index of the row holding the maximum value in that column.
If the two row index are the same, you have a saddle point.

Something like:

```
for r=0 to x-1    // iterates through every row

    // Check min-max combination

    c = min_in_row(r)       //find index of the column holding the minimum value in row r

    r2 = max_in_column(c)   //find index of the row holding the maximum value in column c

    if (r == r2)
    {
        // Saddle point found
        printf("r=%d c=%d value %d is a saddle point\n", r, c, A[r][c]);
    }

    // Repeat the same for the max-min combination
```

Comment: How would I store all the positions of the saddle points found and return them once the whole array has been gone through, rather than printing them one at a time?

Comment: @ShaynaGrose - Make a `struct point {int r; int c;)` then use malloc/realloc to allocate memory for the points found and return the pointer to that memory.

Answer (score 0):

Any saddle point can be stored with (row, column). In C:

```
struct Saddle { int row, col; };
```

If the maximum number of expected saddle points is known a result array may be used:

```
/* max. number of saddle points */
#define MAX_FOUND 16
/* row/col. of found saddle points */
struct Saddle found[MAX_FOUND];
/* number of found saddle points */
int nFound = 0;
```

To store a new result:

```
found[nFound].row = r;
found[nFound].col = c;
++nFound;
```

If the number of expected saddle points is unknown two options come in mind:

1. make the array size x * y (Hmm.)
2. allocate storage for array using malloc.

For the 2nd option `malloc`/`realloc` can be used.
There is often a trick used: If the storage runs out of memory, the realloc is used to allocate new space for multiple additional elements. Thus, the number of re-allocations is reduced because realloc is counted as "expensive" operation. In this case, two count variables are used: one for the size of allocated array, another for the numbers of actually used elements. Of course, the second must always be less or equal to the first.